# How can I stitch images with the same center but different peripheral content?

Tags: software, image-processing

Looking for help in solving this problem. I want to stitch a series of images together. The easiest way to describe it is, let's say, I am walking down a long street with a repeating pattern of buildings on both sides. So I snap a picture facing down the street which makes the buildings kind of in the peripheral view. Then I move a set number of steps and take another picture, and so on and so forth. How would I stitch these photos together?

Here are samples of the images I am trying to stitch:

[image] 
[image]

These are not camera shots, they are readings from a photon detector tile that is perpendicular to my emitter.

Comment: How do you _want_ to stitch these photos together? What is the desired artistic result?

Comment: In any case, I'm giving a +1 for putting this in a photographic context even though your particular case is with a scientific instrument.

Comment: Are you trying to align them to the centre? Then how do you want to overlay them? Have you looked into focus stacking? Or maybe you want to sum them. ImageJ might be the tool you need, with then right plugin

Comment: so if you stack all the images I have and then play them image by image it looks like a camera pulling out of a tube. I can make a movie but I was wondering if there was a way to join these images to create one continuous image if you know the distance you move between each image

Comment: If you want an image that changes over time, you have a movie or an animation. In any case, not a photography. Look into animated gifs, for example. Or is what you are really looking for a movie that morphs from one image to the next, like google street view?

Comment: @ths, we allow timelapse and even have a tag for it. This is very similar and the software techniques are the same. However, and despite my answer below, I suspect that this is off-topic for a different reason - writing code (I'd suggest that a simple script driving imagemagick is the same as a set of instructions for photoshop and therefore on-topic, but it seems to me that this goes beyond that.

Comment: Wouldn't a panorama stitching program be best for this? It could definitely take the two example images an merge them into one slightly wider image.

Comment: Can you increase the resolution? That will help. Also, putting your camera on a rolling tripod will help. Software such as Photoshop will stitch a panorama together for you if it has enough reference points, but it seems you have very few pixels compared to what a camera will produce.

Answer (score 1):

You can assemble stills into a movie or animated gif using ffmpeg. This is common for timelapses. If your spacing is constant and your filenames are sequential, follow any ffpmeg timelapse tutorial.

The centering is tricky. I had to do this with a single bright spot under a microscope and wrote a python script to do so in post processing (constant focus but changing over hours). Colleagues used labview to recentre the microscope on a more complex image. You might be able to calculate the centroid of your bright area and offset that, as I did on a smaller scale. You might look into OpenCV, but you're likely to be writing code.

Assembling the images into an animation is comparatively easy. If the spacing is known but non-constant you'll have a tricky scripting job on your hands using duplicate frames to pad the results to a constant frame rate.

If you want to interpolate between frames (and I'd be wary of doing this with my data), [ImageMagick's "morph" feature](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/) might help.

Comment: Thanks yeah I was thinking of doing that since the edge of tub is always seen it just decrease in size relative to the frame. thanks for the help I think I can get by with the time-lapse movie in and then go in and do any analysis as a frame by frame basis.

Comment: Best thing I can think of is to stitch your frames like Chris mentioned and then use a program like After Effects to do a 'tracking' frame-by-frame automation on objects that stay in the same place in your desired result.   In the images you show that would be the specs, OR the entire curve of the right round object.  This shows something similar to what i am talking about: https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/tracking-stabilizing-motion-cs5.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hugin to manually align pictures and you can define masks to define what parts of the pictures are going to be Excluded or stitched. See [Hugin website](Http://hugin.sf.net)